# Vue.js doesn't render table

Tags: vue.js

My template is:

```
        <tbody id="deliveries-table">
         <tr v-for="item in deliveries">
            <td class="table-view-item__col"></td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col" v-bind:class="{ table-view-item__col--extra-status: item.exclamation }"></td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col">{{item.number}}</td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col"><a href="{{item.sender_profile_url}}">{{item.sender_full_name}}</a></td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col" v-if="item.courier_profile_url"><a href="{{item.courier_profile_url}}">{{item.courier_full_name}}</a></td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col" v-if="item.delivery_provider_url"><a href="{{item.delivery_provider_url}}">{{item.delivery_provider_name}}</a></td>
            <td class="table-view-item__col">
              <span style="font-weight: 900">{{item.get_status_display}}</span><br>
              <span>{{item.date_state_updated}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

My javascript code for render a lot of prepared data is:

```
var monitorActiveDeliveries = new ActiveDeliveries();
monitorActiveDeliveries.fillTable(allDeliveries);
class ActiveDeliveries {
  constructor() {
    this.table = new Vue({
      el: '#deliveries-table',
      data: {
        deliveries: []
      }
    });
  }
  fillTable (d) {
    this.table.deliveries = d;
  }
}
```

But after script starts any render into tbody, i have just empty place in HTML.
Where i got some wrong?

Comment: are you sure your `fillTable()` method gets called, i.e.`deliveries` actually contains some records? Do you see any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Probably `d` is not what you expect. Did you check what is `d` gets passed?

Comment: yes, allDeliveries has a lot of data and this data pass to d variable correctly (i see it in console.log)

Answer (score 0):

First, although you *can* instantiate your Vue app on the `<table>` tag, usually you want just a [single Vue instance on the whole page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/new-vue-instance-for-every-component), so it might be better to make the Vue instance on one main div/body tag.

Second, I think your code could work (I don't know what your deliveries objects should look like...), but your `fillTable()` method is probably not getting called, i.e. deliveries are empty.

I made this working example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/wmh29mds/

Answer (score 0):

Life is easier than it seems.
I got a mistake into this directive:

```
v-bind:class="{ table-view-item__col--extra-status: item.exclamation }"
```

I just forgot single quotas into class name, next variant is working:

```
v-bind:class="{ 'table-view-item__col--extra-status': item.exclamation }"
```